# В run time получить список параметров хранимой процедуры со значениями в виде выборки из двух столбцов (param_name, value)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть процедура с параметрами, например такими:

```
alter proc ATATA
@par1 int
@par2 varchar(2)
@par3 bit
```

Задача: Во время исполнения этой процедуры (А именно: exec ATATA 11, 'TESTTEXT', 0) получить выборку из двух столбцов. В первом столбце имя параметра, во втором его значение.

```
@par1     11
@par2     TESTTEXT
@par3     0
```

Пока что нашел только как получить список параметров по имени процедуры:

```
select PARAMETER_NAME, PARAMETER_MODE, DATA_TYPE, * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS
where SPECIFIC_NAME = '<имя процедуры>'
```

Есть догадка, что значения параметров во время исполнения процедуры хранятся в какой-то временной таблице. Но это всего лишь догадка.

Я думаю не стоит говорить о том, что вариант с ручным занесением этих параметров в таблицу (которая будет являться конечной выборкой) откидывается сам собой. Логично, что решение такой задачи нужно для процедур, количество параметров которых больше чем в примере.

Как в run time получить список параметров хранимой процедуры со значениями в виде выборки из двух столбцов (param_name, value)?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кроме как вручную, по крайней мере два решения возможны.

**Решение 1** - полуавтоматическое.

После создания хранимой процедуры выполняется вспомогательный скрипт:

```
declare @procName sysname = '[dbo].[ATATA]';
select '
select name, value
from (values ' + stuff(
    (select ',
    ' + '(' + cast(parameter_id as varchar(10)) + ', ''' + name + '''' +
    ', cast(' + name + ' as sql_variant))'
from sys.parameters
where object_id = object_id(@procName)
order by parameter_id
for xml path(''), type).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') + '
    ) p(num, name, value)
order by num';
```

Результат выполнения скрипта, являющийся текстом следущего вида:

```
select name, value
from (values 
    (1, '@par1', cast(@par1 as sql_variant)),
    (2, '@par2', cast(@par2 as sql_variant)),
    (3, '@par3', cast(@par3 as sql_variant))
    ) p(num, name, value)
order by num
```

копируется и вставляется в тело процедуры в нужном месте.

**Решение 2** - автоматическое.

Задаётся (условно) некий тэг-комментарий следующего, например, вида: `--%%LIST_PARAMS%%`. Затем создаётся DDL-триггер на события `CREATE_PROCEDURE, ALTER_PROCEDURE`. Триггер модифицирует код процедуры, генерируя необходимый код (как в Решении 1), и подменяет этим кодом заданный тэг в теле процедуры. Выглядеть это будет так, что, создавая, например, процедуру скриптом следующего вида:

```
create procedure ATATA
(
    @par1 int,
    @par2 varchar(2),
    @par3 bit
)
as
begin
    set nocount on;

    --%%LIST_PARAMS%%
end
```

Фактически (после срабатывания триггера) в БД она примет вид:

```
create procedure ATATA
(
    @par1 int,
    @par2 varchar(2),
    @par3 bit
)
as
begin
    set nocount on;

    select name, value
    from (values 
        (1, '@par1', cast(@par1 as sql_variant)),
        (2, '@par2', cast(@par2 as sql_variant)),
        (3, '@par3', cast(@par3 as sql_variant))
        ) p(num, name, value)
    order by num
end
```

Оба решения, естественно, обладают определёнными ограничениями в своей применимости.

Comment: Да. Автоматическое решение имеет место быть. Правда я бы его немного подправил. Создал бы не маркер для вставки селекта, а разметил бы область двумя маркерами. А в DDL триггере постоянно обновлял бы эту область. В вашем же случае триггер сработает единожды. В любом случае огромное спасибо за решение.

Comment: @RoulanD, мне привычнее, что код правится не непосредственно в БД (посредством SSMS), а хранится и модифицируется отдельно в Visual Studio проекте. Т.е. источник скрипта всегда во вне, и маркер там всегда будет. Хотя случается править и непосредственно в БД. Так что, в общем, да, справедливое и полезное замечание, согласен.